# Regular expressions: how to make java treat polish letters as normal \w?

Tags: java, regex

Java treat polish letter like `ó` not as a letter `\w`.
Now I don't know how to write a regex to fulfill all following unit tests.

**How to change `BEFORE_LANGUAGE` and `AFTER_LANGUAGE` to fulfull the tests:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class tmpTest extends TestCase{

    final String BEFORE_LANGUAGE = "(?<![\\w\\p{S}])";
    final String AFTER_LANGUAGE = "\\d*((?![\\w\\p{S}])|(<))";


    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // Given:
        String language = ".net";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx .net";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertTrue(m.find());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // Given:
        String language = ".net";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx .net<br>";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertTrue(m.find());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        // Given:
        String language = "c++";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx c++";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertTrue(m.find());
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        // Given:
        String language = "c";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx c++";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertFalse(m.find());
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        // Given:
        String language = "r";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx różne";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertFalse(m.find());
    }

    @Test
    public void test6() {
        // Given:
        String language = "r";
        String text = "xxxxxxx xxx r";
        String regex = BEFORE_LANGUAGE + Pattern.quote(language) + AFTER_LANGUAGE;

        // When: 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

        // Then:
        assertTrue(m.find());
    }

}
```

Comment: `\p{IsAlphabetic}` maybe?

Comment: yes, `final String AFTER_LANGUAGE = "\\d*((?![\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{S}])|<)";` now it worsk. Thank you!

Comment: `\p{Alnum}` includes all Unicode characters and decimal digits, like `\w`.

Comment: `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(text);`

Comment: There is no need rewriting the pattern. `(?U)\w` matches all Unicode letters and digits and some more chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{IsAlphabetic}` matches anything in Unicode that is considered a letter.

`\w` also includes `0-9`, so you need to put `\d` in the character class as well.

So,

```
[\p{IsAlphabetic}\d]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `\w` and other shorthand character classes Unicode-aware pass the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag to the compiled pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(text);
```

No need to rewrite the current pattern.